# In Matthew 11:14, is it "receive it" or "receive him"?

Tags: greek, matthew, referent-identification

In Matthew 11:14, is it "receive [it]" or "receive [him]"? The word "it" is usually supplied by the translators and commentators but is absent from the text:

> (Greek NT)  καὶ εἰ θέλετε δέξασθαι, αὐτός ἐστιν ᾿Ηλίας ὁ
>   μέλλων ἔρχεσθαι.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both classical and Koine Greek, δέχομαι can be used in both senses—that is, accepting or receiving someone<sup>1</sup> or something.<sup>2</sup> However, because John the Baptist was in prison, it is doubtful that the Lord Jesus Christ used that verb in the sense of receiving “someone” (John himself) rather than “something”—that is, accepting and understanding the belief that John the Baptist was the Elijah who was going to come.

---

### Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> Matt. 10:40
<sup>2</sup> Luke 8:13

Comment: (+1) for answering the question. However, isn't what they were to receive the idea that a man named John fulfilled a promise about the return of Elijah?

Comment: But couldn't we say that they were to receive John?

Comment: @WoundedEgo - The people had already received John as a prophet, so the only thing left was for them to receive the idea that he was the "Elijah" that was to come. So the use of "it" is more proper here.

Comment: @Bʀɪᴀɴ   I understand the way it is commonly understood but isn't it possible to see it as "receive him"? That is the original question.

Comment: Accepted as an answer.